# Sum of integers ranging between “a” to “b” gives wrong result for large inputs

Tags: java, math, multiplication

Why is the following code is not giving expected output even though it works for some small inputs? Here I am expecting the sum of all integers in the range between "a" and "b". Is the logic used wrong or are some other things wrong?

```
class RangeSum {
    public static void main(String args[] ){

       // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        long i = Long.valueOf("99");
        long j = Long.valueOf("1000000000000");
        long ans = 0L;
        /*if(i<0 || i>Math.pow(10, 18)){
            //throw new Exception("Wroong Input.");
        }
        if(i<0 || i>Math.pow(10, 18)){
            //throw new Exception("Wroong Input.");
        }*/
        if (j>i){
             long sumTill_j = (j*(j+1))/2;
             long sumTill_i = ((i-1)*i)/2;
             ans = sumTill_j - sumTill_i;
             System.out.println(ans);
        }else{
             long sumTill_i = (i*(i+1))/2;
             long sumTill_j = ((j-1)*j)/2;           
             ans = sumTill_i - sumTill_j;
             System.out.println(ans);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewMata:  *Definitely* overflow.  The sum exceeds what a flow can represent by a decent amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).  What this means is, even though you're using the largest primitive you can (`long`), the value you're trying to calculate exceeds the maximum representable value.

A long can only store a value that is 2<sup>63</sup>-1, [which is around 9 quintillion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E63-1), or 9.22 * 10<sup>18</sup>.  The value that you're trying to generate from your sum *exceeds* that value [with a difference of around ***499 sextillion***.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+i+%3D+0+to+1000000000000+of+i+%3E+2%5E63-1)

Don't fret; you can still calculate this insanely large value, but you have to make a few changes, notably, you can no longer use `long`.  Move to [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead.

You can't use any of the primitive operators instead, but you can call functions which you would expect to be available, such as `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, and `divide`.

Here is the first part of the code converted to use it; I leave the other half as an exercise for the reader.

```
BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(99L);
BigInteger j = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000000000L);
BigInteger ans = BigInteger.ZERO;
if (j.compareTo(i) > 0) {
    BigInteger sumTill_j = (j.multiply(j.add(BigInteger.ONE))).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2L));
    BigInteger sumTill_i = ((i.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(i)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2L));
    ans = sumTill_j.subtract(sumTill_i);
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer!!

Comment: 10^21 is not insanely large.  There's even a standard SI prefix for it ... zetta.  (And that's more standard than "sextillion".)

Comment: @reasonable_syam if some answer helps you, [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) instead of thank. If you're new to SO have a look at the top menu and [took a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first

Answer (score 5):

The largest possible number that you can represent in a `long` is 2<sup>63</sup> - 1, which is about 9.2 x 10<sup>18</sup>.  If your calculation exceeds that, then the calculation will overflow *without any exceptions being thrown* and you will get the wrong answer.

In your case:

```
1,000,000,000,000 * (1,000,000,000,000 + 1) / 2
```

is about 5 x 10<sup>23</sup> if my mental arithmetic is correct.  That will overflow.

---

Solution: use `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

`1000000000000 = 0xE8D4A51000` which needs at least 40 bits to store. Therefore multiplying `j` by `j+1` needs an 80-bit type to store. The result is overflowing `long` type as it has only 64 bits. If you really want to do that the only way is using a bigint type like `BigInteger`

Btw why don't just use `99L` and `1000000000000L`? Calling `valueOf` is just redundant and slow

```
long i = Long.valueOf("99");
long j = Long.valueOf("1000000000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: `j * (j + 1)` gets overflow when `j = 1,000,000,000,000`.

Java's [signed long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) has 64 bits, which has `2^63 - 1` or `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` as the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

Your integers are too high in value. Try using another type of integer instead, as it will help those larger values. Here is a good website that explains `BigInteger` in detail: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/java_math_biginteger.htm

Comment: please add some details (e.g. what other type of integer?) because the link may not be accessible forever

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that website offers that isn't already at the official api: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html.  You may want to ask yourself if your answer provides anything that isn't already in the accepted answer.